# Unload Prefetched Page using jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

With jQuery Mobile, I can manually prefetch an external page like so:

```
$.mobile.loadPage(
  "content.html",
  { showLoadMsg: true }
);
```

But ow do I manually remove that page from the memory; in a sense, "unload" it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your jqm-page if there's a `id` specified, you can do this.

```
$('#page2').remove();
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/ituket)

another way is to use `$.fn.jqmData(), $.fn.jqmRemoveData()`
refer [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html)